# java sample to make JLabel text glow or neon

Tags: java

Does anyone have sample java code to make a  JLabel with something that looks like glow or neon text.

Some answers mention "blurring". I would be grateful if someone could post a simple but complete example.

---

I don't believe this is a duplicate question. I have seen similar but no full answers.

EDIT 1

I found this on web for Maven (Not on JHLabs site unfortunately):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcaptcha-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC-2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jhlabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>filters</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.235</version>
     </dependency>
```

and the I put this import:

```
import com.jhlabs.image.*;
```

I still can't find JHLabsLabel...

Comment: Why don't you post an pic of an example

Answer (score 2):

use an `ImageIcon` on `JLabel` with animation you want, like this:

```
ImageIcon gifImage = new ImageIcon(new URL("file:/Path/To/file.gif"));
JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel(gifImage);
```

Comment: Nice idea but I want to change label text on the fly.